# pushing a string into array return a number and not the actual string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying pushing the name but in the console log I see just a number and not the actual name

What am i doing wrong??

```js
const cartItems = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Soup",
    price: 3,
    category: "starters",
    count: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Pâté",
    price: 5,
    category: "starters",
    count: 1
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "Sticky toffee",
    price: 18,
    category: "desserts",
    count: 1
  }
]


var dishesArray = [];
var groupByCategory = []
cartItems.reduce(function(res, value) {
  if (!res[value.category]) {
    res[value.category] = {
      category: value.category,
      count: 0,
      dishes: dishesArray.push(value.name), // problem here
    };
    groupByCategory.push(res[value.category]);
  }
  res[value.category].count += value.count;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(groupByCategory)
```

Expected output

```
[{category: "starters", count: 2, dishes:["Soup","Pâté"]},
 {category: "desserts", count: 1, dishes:["Sticky toffee"]}]
```

Comment: That's just how [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) works: _"The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**."_

Comment: You likely meant to do `if (!res[value.category]) { dishesArray.push(value.name); res[value.category] = { category: value.category, count: 0, dishes: dishesArray };`

Comment: You could just [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and add the new value into the array like: `dishes: [...dishesArray, value.name]`

Comment: @Reyno it actually works but it pushes just one element, I wanted to make it push every dish of the same category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, a push returns an int

I believe you are looking for this much shortened reduce

```js
const cartItems = [
  { id: 1, name: "Soup", price: 3, category: "starters", count: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: "Pâté", price: 5, category: "starters", count: 1 },
  { id: 9, name: "Sticky toffee", price: 18, category: "desserts", count: 1}
];

const groupByCategory = cartItems.reduce(function(res, value) {
  const cat = value.category;
  res[cat] = res[cat] ||  { category: cat, count: 0, dishes: [] };
  res[cat].count += value.count;
  res[cat].dishes.push(value.name)
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(groupByCategory)
```